# I want a alert box to come up when records are updated

Tags: php

I have php file where i need to check if variables are not empty and then update the table.Everything works fine except alert.

```
<?php




$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");


mysql_select_db("sg",$con);
  error_reporting(0);
$result1=mysql_query("select DeclarationNo,DeclarantReferenceNo from sg_report where DeclarationNo='$dec' OR DeclarantReferenceNo='$dec'");
if(isset($_POST['myText'])){ $cn = $_POST['myText']; } 
if(isset($_POST['myText1'])){ $dec = $_POST['myText1']; }
if(isset($_POST['tb3'])){ $rem = $_POST['tb3']; }


I want a alert box to come up when records are updated

 if( !empty($dec) && !empty($rem)  ){

$result=mysql_query("update sg_report set CreditNoteStatus='$cn',Remarks='$rem' where DeclarationNo='$dec' OR DeclarantReferenceNo='$dec'");
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updated successfully!');</script>";
}
```

I want a alert box to come up if all values are not entered

```
if(empty($dec) || empty($rem) ) {  
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"Please enter all Values\");window.location=\"view3.php\";</script>";

    } 





?>
```

Comment: What is wrong with alert and why you are not using Ajax to make interactions?

Comment: The echo alert line itself works fine. check if your query is actually run and use `var_dump()` to check if your variables really contain what you think.

Comment: Side note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and shouldn't be used to write new code. They will be removed from future versions of PHP and your code will stop working then. [Use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). Also, you are open for SQL injections.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one

```
if(trim($_POST['myText'])!=''&&trim($_POST['myText1'])!=''&&trim($_POST['tb3'])!='')
{
    $result=mysql_query("update sg_report set CreditNoteStatus='$cn',Remarks='$rem' where DeclarationNo='$dec' OR DeclarantReferenceNo='$dec'");
    if($result)
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updated successfully!');</script>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"Please enter all Values\");window.location=\"view3.php\";</script>";
}
```

Comment: This will report success even if only one variable is set.

Comment: Plz try it now I have updated the answer with "if(trim($_POST['myText'])!=''||trim($_POST['myText1'])!=''||trim($_POST['tb3'])!='')"

Comment: The edit doesn't make any difference. You are still using `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: oh sorry. I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['myText']) && isset($_POST['myText1']) && isset($_POST['tb3']))
{
$result=mysql_query("update sg_report set CreditNoteStatus='$cn',Remarks='$rem' where DeclarationNo='$dec' OR DeclarantReferenceNo='$dec'");
if($result)
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updated successfully!');</script>";
}
}
else
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"Please enter all Values\");window.location=\"view3.php\";</script>";
}
```